# Retrieve data from InAppBrowser to the app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, inappbrowser, ionic-native

Is it possible to do a login page in InAppBrowser and then retrieve token to the app to use?

Comment: Can you show us what did you try so far?

Comment: I used InAppBrowser before, but have never tried retrieving something from there.If I understand correct, in the docs the API is only provide operations within the box but not out. I was thinking that `eventlisteners` is the place to go, but wanted to ask folks beforehand.